# Copying a particular keyword from doc file and saving it into a .txt file

Tags: python

This is the code:

```
print ("Enter first the source file and then destination file with respective format")
t=input()                    #Enter source file
t1=input()                   #Enter destination file
print ("Enter the keyword which has to be copied into another file")
find=input()                 #Enter the keyword which has to be copied
f=open(t,encoding="utf-8")                    #Open the source file
f1=open(t1,"a+",encoding="utf-8")             #Open the destination file in append and read mode

Copy_Lines=False         
for line in f.readlines():
    if find in line:
        Copy_Lines=True
        if Copy_Lines:
            f1.write(line)
            f1.close()
            f.close()
print("Task completed")
```

But I'm getting this error and i m just not able to find out the problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sanket_d\Desktop\python files\COPY_ONE.py", line 13, in <module>
    for line in f.readlines():
  File "C:\Python34\lib\codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: The file you opened *is not UTF-8 encoded*.

Comment: thnx fr the input...but am not sure how this error popped up suddenly coz this code was working all fine a day back...how to change the file encoding to utf-8..i think my file is ISO-8859-1 encoded..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martijn Pieters commented your file is not `utf-8` encoded, I have rewritten your code to be more in line with the pep-8 style guide and more readable:

```
print("Enter first the source file and then destination file with respective format")
t = input()  # Enter source file
t1 = input()  # Enter destination file
print("Enter the keyword which has to be copied into another file")
find = input()  # Enter the keyword which has to be copied

with open(t) as f, open(t1, "a+") as f1: # Open the source file and open the destination file in append and read mode
    copy_lines = False         
    for line in f.readlines():
        if find in line:
            copy_lines = True
            if copy_lines:
                f1.write(line)
        print("Task completed")
```

Use lowercase for variable names separating words with with an underscore `_`.

Leave a space between  assignments like `copy_lines = False`  not `copy_lines=False` and a  space between the `#` and your comment like `# mycomment` not `#mycomment`.

Use `with` to open your files as it closes them automatically.

Comment: thanx Padraic.....but still the same error is popping....anything else i can try in this...??

Comment: @sam.k, can you show an example of what is in your file.

Comment: script working fine now....while opening the file i added errors='ignore' along with import codecs....thnxx everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("Enter first the source file and then destination file with respective format")
t=input()                    #Enter source file
t1=input()                   #Enter destination file
print ("Enter the keyword which has to be copied into another file")
find=input()                 #Enter the keyword which has to be copied
f=open(t)                    #Open the source file
f1=open(t1,"a+")             #Open the destination file in append and read mode

Copy_Lines=False         
for line in f.readlines():
    if find in line:
        Copy_Lines=True
        if Copy_Lines:
            f1.write(line)
            f1.close()
            f.close()
print("Task completed")
```